# How to get link to custom post type archive page? [wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have custom posts loop and at the bottom I want to add "View all" link that should lead to the page with all posts of that type.

The only solution I could think of is to have a template page for the post type and hardcode the link to it, but I am hoping for a more elegant and dynamic solution.

I've checked out the Codex and none of the functions seems to cover this.

Thanks

Bojana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I belive you are looking for this `get_post_type_archive_link('post_type');`. More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link

Answer (score 8):

In case `get_post_type_archive_link()` returns `false`, make sure that you have used the argument `has_archive => true` when using `register_post_type()`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer... but I did find it useful.